# Can we objectively determine whether assumptions have been violated in R?

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption, assumptions, diagnostic

I'm testing statistical assumptions in R and so far I've been using `plot(model, which = c(1:6))`, which produces six graphs for linearity, normality of errors, homoscedasticity, outliers and influential cases.

I may have misunderstood the process, but I am wondering whether there are any alternative methods which produce output that explicitly states whether the assumption has been violated (and to what extent), and names outlying/influential cases? If it more objective than that, are there alternative ways to produce output from which I can decide limitations (for the sake of transparency and reproducibility) - or are there existing recommended limitations? I am only aware of that for Cook's distance so far.

In case it is relevant, I am planning to apply this to a mediation model and correlations.

Comment: There is the ```gvlma::gvlma``` function that runs automated tests to assess whether the assumptions have been violated. But I think in general it's considered bad practise. The justification of a model is never purely objective, not all violations make a model completely useless, they rather inform you how to improve the predictions.

Comment: @FelixPhl oh that surprises me... though that makes sense about not being purely objective. Do you mean as in, checking for violations using that method is bad practice? Or checking for violations in general? Thanks

Comment: Checking for violations is certainly a good practise. I mean that relying on a specific test, i.e. whether p is greater than 0.05 or not, that's bad practise. Looking at the plots provides you with more information that you can use to improve the model. In general, it really depends on your specific case. Are you interested in prediction or inference?

Comment: @FelixPhl makes sense. I'm interested in inference

Comment: If you are using real world data, it is quite unlikely that your relationship between X and Y is linear and that is most likely the most concerning violation. You can try replacing ```X``` in your model with ```rcs(X,k)``` and start with k=3. See if that gives you better results. If you replace ```lm``` with ```ols``` from the ```rms``` package, you can run the functions ```anova(model)``` and ```ggplot(Predict(model))```. These two will give you a better idea of the true relationship.